# How do I bind a list of objects with composite-key to a checkbox list?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a list of objects that contain a composite key because of the legacy database that supports multi-tenancy. How can I then bind that list to a checkbox list in asp.net? We're currently using c# 3.5.

Here's the class:

```
public class SiteKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public SiteKey Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My repository returns an `IList<Order>` that I want to then bind to a checkbox list.
This code:

```
chkList.DataValueField = "Key";
chkList.DataTextField = "Name";
```

displays properly, but the value (`chkList.Items[0].Value`) coming back simply contains "MyAssemblyName.SiteKey" and not the key.

How can I effectively accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override ToString() on SiteKey to return a concatenated string containing string representations of the properties that make up the primary key. You'll then have to parse the Value property of the item to retrieve the keys.

```
public class SiteKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id.ToString() + "|" + CustomerId.ToString();
    }
}
```

and in the method that retrieves the key:

```
string[] siteKey = chkList.Items[0].Value.Split('|');
int id = int.Parse(siteKey[0]);
int customerId = int.Parse(siteKey[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Jamie's suggestion is good, but instead of overriding ToString(), I would just project your IList<Order> into IEnumerable<ListItem> before binding:

ie:

```
var items = 
    from o in dataList // dataList being IList returned from repository
    select new ListItem(o.Name, 
                        String.Format("{0}|{1}", 
                                      o.Key.Id, o.Key.CustomerId));

// ... bind items to dropdown ...
```

I prefer this rather than overriding ToString(), as ToString() is generic and used everywhere and can therefore be a pain in the arse, whereas this is a local modification that doesn't affect anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to modify the Order class? Using SiteKey as the valuefield return Type (unless you override the ToString() method).

```
public class Order
{
    public SiteKey Key { get; set; }
    public int KeyId { get{return Key.Id;} }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

chkList.DataValueField = "KeyId";
chkList.DataTextField = "Name";
```